# Unable to recieve full list of data with the Spotify API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, spotify

I'm using the Spotify API and I'm trying to retrieve a full list of songs in a playlist which I did but it only receives 100 results. I want the limit to be at least 500, this is what I have now:

```
const fetchPlaylistItems = async () => {
  return await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlistToShuffle}/tracks`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
}
```

I tried adding `?offset=0&limit=500` to the end of the fetch URL but it didn't work.
I'm doing this project in ReactJs and need to be able to store a list of the ENTIRE list of songs. The Spotify API does have a key that says next with a link to the next 100 songs as you can see here.

[image: API results]

So if anyone has any ideas on what to do I'd really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: From what am seeing in the docs, unless am missing something, not only you can't get 500, but it's a bug your getting 100, `The maximum number of items to return. Default: 20. Minimum: 1. Maximum: 50.` https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-playlists-tracks

Comment: @Roy.B I was confused by that as well, I read that in confusion as I was getting 100 results lol. I do think you can get more because it mentions a default value and a "maximum" implying it can be changed... I just don't know how. Their API documentation is all over the place.

Comment: maybe they changed the max and didn't update the docs, try passing `limit=90` and see if you get 90 items, If so, that means your passing it correctly, but the max is indeed 100, and you can't get more than that

Comment: @Roy.B I just did what you suggested, setting the limit to 90 that is. You were indeed correct :( it seems you can only request 100 songs but they make it impossible to receive the next page of results. There must be a way lol